# Spectrum of $\Delta+a$ on a compact manifold, where $a$ is a function

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian, elliptic-equations

Let $(M,g)$ be a closed Riemannian manifold and $\Delta$ be its Laplace-Beltrami operator. It is well known that the spectrum of $\Delta$ is a discrete subset of $[0,+\infty)$ and the eigenfunctions form an orthogonal basis of the Hilbert space $W^{1,2}(M)$. My question is:

> **Question:** Given $a\in C^\infty(M)$, does the operator $Lf:=\Delta f+af$ have the same spectral property as $\Delta$ (except that the interval $[0,+\infty)$ should be replaced by $[\lambda_0,+\infty)$, where $\lambda_0$ is the lowest eigenvalue)?

My background on analysis is quite limited, so any hint about the ideas behind this kind of results and their generalizations would be appreciated!

Comment: I thought the spectrum of $\Delta$ is in $(-\infty, 0]$, don't you mean $-\Delta$?

Comment: @lisyarus In Riemannian geometry, we often (If not almost always) define $\Delta$ to be a positive operator, and its spectrum is non-negative. This is your $-\Delta$.

Comment: [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/220229/90655) similar post without answer.